# How do I make buttons stay active rather than revert to normal state?

Tags: html, css, button, touch, state

I want touchscreen buttons that stay depressed while the page is active rather than revert to normal state.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Ie, you're on the main page, there are three buttons, you press a button, it takes you to the new page and shades a different color.

The code I'm working with looks like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Name" class="Class" onclick="location.href='#';">
```

CSS:

```
.class {display:inline;border:solid #000 3px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding:10px;font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:600;
color:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;   -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;  border-radius: 0.5em;
background: #aaa; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #636363 0%, #ffffff 4%, #000000 75%, #ffff00 97%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#636363), color-stop(4%,#ffffff), color-stop(75%,#000000), color-stop(97%,#ffff00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #636363 0%,#ffffff 4%,#000000 75%,#ffff00 97%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #636363 0%,#ffffff 4%,#000000 75%,#ffff00 97%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #636363 0%,#ffffff 4%,#000000 75%,#ffff00 97%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #636363 0%,#ffffff 4%,#000000 75%,#ffff00 97%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#636363', endColorstr='#ffff00',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

}

```
.class:active {background: #bababa; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bababa 1%, #636363 69%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#bababa), color-stop(69%,#636363), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bababa 1%,#636363 69%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bababa 1%,#636363 69%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bababa 1%,#636363 69%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bababa 1%,#636363 69%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is assign some sort off 'active' class to the link (eather on the server side, of by using some javascript), and give it the same styling as your hover state. Something like this:

```
#menu a:hover, #menu a.active {
  background: #[PressedStateColor];
}
```

You could add the 'active' class with some easy javascript (jQuery) like this:

```
// when the dom is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // for each of the links in the #menu
    $('#menu a').each(function() {
        // if the href of the link matches the one for the current page
        if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) {
            // add the class 'active' to the link
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }    
    });
});
```

Note that this is not foolproof, it will only work on simple url's. Personally I would go for a server side solution.

To demonstrate, I set up a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyHse/

Comment: @annoyingnewbie,  what exactly doesn't work? Did you have a look at the fiddle?

Comment: i have tried to implement that - it still does not appear to be working. i might be doing something stupid however. the website for reference is www.interimspaces.co.uk shrunk to 480 pixels wide for mobiles. those are the buttons i'm trying to modify...

Comment: note that you are using relative links (which i would advise against) so my js would not work in your case. The solution @vector provided should work fine however. (could cause you trouble if you where linking to a diffrent domain, but that is unlikely) Also note that the  href of your 'home' link should contain just a '/' to make  that work.